# Android MessageQueue max size

Tags: android

Does Android MessageQueue, the one that Handler post to, is limited in size ?

The following code throws messages to the message queue and behaves like a loop, something that I'm not sure I know to explain:

```
private void startTracking()
{
    mIsTracking = true;

    mTrackingHandler.post( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if( !mIsTracking )
                return;

            mHeadTracker.getLastHeadView( mHeadTransform.getHeadView(), 0 );
            mTrackingHandler.postDelayed( this, 10 );
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit, but application can crash with OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 0):

[50](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Message.java#114)

However you don't have to worry about going over the limit if you use Message.obtain().

The preferred way to get a Message is to call {@link #obtain() Message.obtain()} [[2]](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Message.java#473).

While the constructor of Message is public, the best way to get
 * one of these is to call {@link #obtain Message.obtain()} or one of the
 * {@link Handler#obtainMessage Handler.obtainMessage()} methods, which will pull
 * them from a pool of recycled objects. [[3]](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Message.java#473)